# Why is toDouble and toInt not working in my project

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am trying to write a class which will help me convert certain numbers that i am getting from an json to those particular types meaning int->int and double->double. but when i try using it the console says that there are not such methods

The full class TypeHelper:-

```
    class TypeHelper{

  int toint(num val){
    if(val is int){
      return val;
    }else{
      return val.toInt();
    }
  }

  double toDoub(num val){
    if(val is double){
     return val;
    }else{
      return val.toDouble();
    }
    }


}
```

Comment: `method toInt was called on null`.

Comment: where are you calling this functions? it seems you're passing null values

Comment: the error message say why.. Because it was called on null... which means your variable was null

Comment: check, if the error occur when you use `int toint({@required num val}){` ...

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you're calling `toInt()` on a null object. I'm guessing that you declared a `TypeHelper` object without initializing it.

What you can do instead is make both methods `static`. That way, you can call `TypeHelper.toInt()`. You can even get rid of the `TypeHelper` class and declare the methods as top-level functions.

Or you can extend the num type with new methods. For that, see [Extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)